# Subset dataframe if a $ symbol exists in a string column

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, subset

I have a `dataframe` with a `time` column and a `string` column. I want to `subset` this `dataframe` - where I only keep the rows in which the `string` column contains a `$` symbol somewhere in it.

After subsetting, I want to clean the `string` column so that it only contains the `characters` after the `$` symbol until there is a `space` or `symbol`

```
df <- data.frame("time"=c(1:10),
"string"=c("$ABCD test","test","test $EFG test",
"$500 test","$HI/ hello","test $JK/",
"testing/123","$MOO","$abc","123"))
```

I want the final output to be:

```
Time  string  
1     ABCD
3     EFG
4     500
5     HI
6     JK
8     MOO
9     abc
```

It only keeps rows that have a `$` in the string column, and then only keeps the characters after the `$` symbol and until a `space` or `symbol`

I have had some success with `sub` simply to pull out the `string`, but haven't been able to apply that to the `df` and subset it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this by extracting the substring with `regexpr/regmatches` to extract only substring that follows a `$`

```
i1 <- grep("$", df$string, fixed = TRUE)
transform(df[i1,], string = regmatches(string, regexpr("(?<=[$])\\w+", string, perl = TRUE)))
#    time string
#1    1   ABCD
#3    3    EFG
#4    4    500
#5    5     HI
#6    6     JK
#8    8    MOO
#9    9    abc
```

---

Or with the `tidyverse` syntax

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   filter(str_detect(string, fixed("$")))  %>%
   mutate(string = str_extract(string, "(?<=[$])\\w+"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Until someone comes up with pretty [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) solutions, here is my take:

```
# subset for $ signs and convert to character class
res <- df[ grepl("$", df$string, fixed = TRUE),]
res$string <- as.character(res$string)

# split on non alpha and non $, and grab the one with $, then remove $
res$clean <- sapply(strsplit(res$string, split = "[^a-zA-Z0-9$']", perl = TRUE),
                    function(i){
                      x <- i[grepl("$", i, fixed = TRUE)]
                      # in case when there is more than one $
                      # x <- i[grepl("$", i, fixed = TRUE)][1]
                      gsub("$", "", x, fixed = TRUE)
                    })
res
#   time         string clean
# 1    1     $ABCD test  ABCD
# 3    3 test $EFG test   EFG
# 4    4      $500 test   500
# 5    5     $HI/ hello    HI
# 6    6      test $JK/    JK
# 8    8           $MOO   MOO
# 9    9           $abc   abc
```

Comment: This is great thank you. One thing I ran into when I ran it on my dataset that I didn't foresee - some of the strings actually have multiple occurrences of `$string` - for example, one value may be `$ABCD test $EBC and $FB` - this results in a value of `c("ABCD","EBC","FB")`. Is it possible to store just the first occurrence? Thanks!

Comment: @newtoR use this line to get only the first occurance `x <- i[grepl("$", i, fixed = TRUE)][1]`, added to the post as comment